# where has android command line gone ?

Tags: android

In the releases from AndroidStudio 2.3, the command line tools like **android create project** have gone. Two other tools have been introduced: **sdkmanager** and **avdmanager** but it seems that there is nothing similar for creating an android project from  command line. Is there any explanation about that ? And is there a workaround for those who like using the command line ?

Comment: I have a "Terminal" tab in my Android Studio...

Comment: @Fustigador yes but it's for adb operations mainly, not for creating or updating projects ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per android docs, the manual command line tools are no longer supported in android studio

https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android.html

For adb operations, you can use terminal in android studio

**Update**

You can use `skdmanager` to use command line. More details [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks but i wonder if there is any workaround available to manage projects via the command line ?

Comment: Thanks @Arun, i've read that but the command line tools available are anly for installing packages and managing the AVD not for creating or managing android projects

Comment: as i understand, you can't use command line with android studio to manage project anymore. you have to use the UI